# Are the drivers for SenseiDB Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

SenseiDB has Python drivers but it doesn't say which version of Python the support.  I am wondering if they support version 3?

http://senseidb.github.com/sensei/client-python.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their download link is broken, but I dug up the code here:

https://github.com/linkedin/sensei/blob/master/clients/python/sensei/sensei_client_lib.py

The `import urllib2` line means it must be Python 2 code. If you've got time to make it compatible with Python 3, they might accept it as a contribution.